# Update many documents in MongoDb from a JSON file using a common custom index

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

New to Mongo and have been reading up on the Mongo documentation for UpdateMany, but I can't seem to find an answer to my specific scenario.

Let's say I have a collection, MyCollection. I create a new unique index in MyCollection on the property MyExternalId, which will be present on all documents in MyCollection. I insertMany documents and load the following JSON file:

```
[
 {
   "Name": "John Everyman",
   "MyExternalId": "A001"
 },
 {
   "Name": "Robert Smith",
   "MyExternalId": "A002"
 },
{
   "Name": "Kevin Bacon",
   "MyExternalId": "A003"
 }
]
```

MyCollection has three documents, each with the two properties outlined in the JSON file above.

Now I get a new JSON file that has the same MyExternalIds but a new property I'd like to add. Let's say the file is as follows:

```
[
 {
   "MyExternalId": "A001",
   "FaveDrink": "Pepsi"
 },
 {
   "MyExternalId": "A003",
   "FaveDrink": "Coke"
 }
]
```

I'd like to run an update using the second JSON file as the data source, and using the MyExternalId property as the index to update any documents that match MyExternalId. So in theory, after the update, MyCollection would have the following three documents:

```
[
 {
   "Name": "John Everyman",
   "MyExternalId": "A001",
   "FaveDrink": "Pepsi"
 },
 {
   "Name": "Robert Smith",
   "MyExternalId": "A002"
 },
{
   "Name": "Kevin Bacon",
   "MyExternalId": "A003",
   "FaveDrink": "Coke"
 }
]
```

Looking over the UpdateMany() documentation I see the ability to pass a query criteria to identify documents, but I can't figure out if there is a way to load the JSON file with the index and tell UpdateMany() command to use that MyExternalId index as the matching criteria.

Is this something that you can do in Mongo? Or is query-based updates the only way to update records?

Comment: Are you looking for `--mode merge` of he `mongoimport` utility additionally with the `upsertFields` option? [Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/#std-option-mongoimport.--mode)

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I overlooked; I'm just an idiot and didn't realize there was a separate command line toolset to load data. Downloaded this toolset and a quick command " mongoimport --db MyDatabase --collection MyCollection --mode merge --upsertFields "MyExternalId" --file <pathToFile>\loadFile.json --jsonArray" later, my merge worked successfully. Thank you so much for the quick answer!